# Encoding/Getting single result from array

Tags: php, json, var

So I have this array

```
object(stdClass)#19 (2) { ["status"]=> string(7) "success" ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#14 (6) { ["network"]=> string(3) "BTC" ["txid"]=> string(64) "128830010b4773bb9a88f9c53b67217f37caa092bfd477a81a2f41d6ea804e53" ["amount_withdrawn"]=> string(10) "0.00087298" ["amount_sent"]=> string(10) "0.00050000" ["network_fee"]=> string(10) "0.00037298" ["blockio_fee"]=> string(10) "0.00000000" } }
```

But I am not sure how to get the single data such as txid, Im not sure whether its json or..

Answer (score 0):

this is how :

```
  $myarray = (array) $my_var ; // what u have is a class and not an array, just cast it

 echo $myarray["data"]["txid"];
```